# wxWidgets program seg faulting

Tags: c++, macos, segmentation-fault, wxwidgets

I just started an irc client project using wxWidgets on OS X (10.11.3 (15D21)).

However, when I compile the code and run it, it seg faults for some reason. I ran the program with gdb and got the output below.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff9793871a in std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

My code hasn't strayed to far away from the hello world tutorial on the wxWidgets website so I'm not sure why I'm having this problem. Based on the gdb output, the issue seems to be related to `std::string::assign()`. The only place i can see this getting called down the line from is the construction of wxFrame where the title gets passed in?

main.hpp

```
#ifndef __main_hpp
#define __main_hpp

#include <sockit.hpp>
#include <wx/wxprec.h>

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include "frame.hpp"

class IrcClientApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.hpp"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(IrcClientApp);

bool IrcClientApp::OnInit() {
    IrcClientFrame* frame = new IrcClientFrame("IRC client", wxPoint(100, 100), wxSize(600, 400));
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

frame.hpp

```
#ifndef __frame_hpp
#define __frame_hpp

class IrcClientFrame : public wxFrame {
private:
    void about(wxCommandEvent&);
    void exit(wxCommandEvent&);

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();

public:
    IrcClientFrame(const wxString&, const wxPoint&, const wxSize&);
};

#endif
```

frame.cpp

```
#include "main.hpp"

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(IrcClientFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, IrcClientFrame::about)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

IrcClientFrame::IrcClientFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) :
    wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) {

    // About menu item
    wxMenu* menu_about = new wxMenu;
    menu_about->Append(wxID_ABOUT);

    // Menu bar
    wxMenuBar* menu_bar = new wxMenuBar;
    menu_bar->Append(menu_about, "&Help");

    // Set it
    SetMenuBar(menu_bar);

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("This is the status text!");
}

void IrcClientFrame::about(wxCommandEvent& e) {
    wxMessageBox("Hello world", "Hello world", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}

void IrcClientFrame::exit(wxCommandEvent& e) {
    Close(true);
}
```

Compiled using the following Makefile

```
CC=g++
WXCONFIG=$(shell ../../../deps/bin/wx-config --cxxflags --libs)
INCLUDES=-I../../../src
CFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override $(INCLUDES)
LDFLAGS=-L../../../deps/lib
BIN=../bin/client
CPPS=main.cpp frame.cpp

all: mkdir_bin examples

examples: $(CPPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(WXCONFIG) $(CPPS) -o $(BIN)

mkdir_bin: ; if [ ! -d ../bin ]; then mkdir ../bin; fi
clean:     ; if [   -d ../bin ]; then rm -rf ../bin; fi
```

Here's the dispatch queue from the crash report

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x1:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000103d8d000-0000000103d93000 [   24K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff9793871a std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) + 26
1   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.dylib 0x00000001041bcfbf wxNonOwnedWindow::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 63
2   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.dylib 0x00000001041c1311 wxTopLevelWindowMac::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 49
3   client                          0x0000000103d912ec wxFrame::wxFrame(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 140 (frame.h:35)
4   client                          0x0000000103d90d2f IrcClientFrame::IrcClientFrame(wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&) + 175 (frame.cpp:8)
5   client                          0x0000000103d9111d IrcClientFrame::IrcClientFrame(wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&) + 45 (frame.cpp:23)
6   client                          0x0000000103d8e9b6 IrcClientApp::OnInit() + 134 (main.cpp:6)
7   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.dylib 0x00000001041b755e wxApp::CallOnInit() + 158
8   libwx_baseu-3.1.dylib           0x00000001048623f9 wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**) + 121
9   client                          0x0000000103d8e8a6 main + 38 (main.cpp:3)
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9740a5ad start + 1
```

Comment: How did you compile it?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, see my edit, i've added the Makefile im using to compile

Comment: Did you install wxWidgets with `homebrew`?

Comment: I compiled it and prefix'd it to the '../../../deps' directory. I should also note this was today, so it's the most recent stable version.

Comment: @Dillan, what is your configure line? Did you compile with Xcode or from Terminal?

Comment: Hi @Igor, i compiled from terminal. `./configure --prefix=/Users/Dillan/Projects/Development/C++/deps/`. Only specified the prefix and no other args. I copy pastad their hello world example, compiled it, and experienced the same problem as my code (no surprise since they're almost the same). I'm guessing it's either an issue with my environment and or wxWidgets :\ I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: @Dillan, did you compile on the same system? Also keep in mind that 10.11 is known to have issues with wxWidgets...

Comment: Yeah i compiled on the same system and I wasn't aware there are known issues with 10.11 and wxWidgets :(

Comment: @Igor Maybe i should open a ticket with wxWidgets?

Comment: @Dillan, can you try to build and run the minimal sample? Also what version of wx you are using - 3.0 or 3.1? Please post compilation command used to compile minimal sample.

Comment: @Igor 3.1 i believe (didn't notice this was the unstable release until just now) and i just ran make in samples/minimal then ./minimal and it runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't build the library with `-std=c++11` but are using it for your own code, this is probably the problem. The recommended approach under OS X is to use `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` for compiling *both* the library and your own code, i.e. remove your old build directory (you did build in a separate directory, didn't you?), then rerun configure with `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"` and make. Finally, update your own makefile to use `-stdlib=libc++` too.